# Search text file for multiple strings and print out results to a new text file

Tags: python, string, file, search, text

I'm fairly new to python programming and I'm trying to learn File I/O as best I can.

I am currently in the process of making a simple program to read from a text document and print out the result. So far I've been able to create this program with the help of many resources and questions on this website.

However I'm curious on how I can read from a text document for multiple individual strings and save the resulting strings to a text document.

The program below is one i've made that allows me to search a text document for a Keyword and print the results between those Keywords into another Text File. However I can only do one set of Starting and Ending Keyword per search:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkSimpleDialog
import tkMessageBox
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text ="Configuration Inspector")
w.pack()
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Welcome", "This is version 1.00 of Configuration Inspector Text")
filename = askopenfilename() # Data Search Text File
outputfilename = askopenfilename() #Output Text File 

with open(filename, "rb") as f_input:
    start_token = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Serial Number", "What is the device serial number?")
    end_token = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("End Keyword", "What is the end keyword")
    reText = re.search("%s(.*?)%s" % (re.escape(start_token + ",SHOWALL"), re.escape(end_token)), f_input.read(), re.S)
    if reText:
        output = reText.group(1)
        fo = open(outputfilename, "wb")
        fo.write(output)
        fo.close()

       print output
    else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Output", "Sorry that input was not found in the file")
        print "not found"
```

So what this program does is, it allows a user to select a text document search that document for a Beginning Keyword and an End Keyword then print out everything in between those two key words into a new text document.

What I am trying to achieve is allow a user to select a text document and search that text document for multiple sets keywords and print the result to the same output text file.

In other words let's say I have the following Text Document:

```
something something something something
something something something something STARTkeyword1 something
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
ENDkeyword1
something something something something
something something something something STARTkeyword2 something
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
Data6
ENDkeyword2
something something something something
something something something something STARTkeyword3 something
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
data6
data7
data8
ENDkeyword3
```

I want to be able to search this text document with 3 different starting keywords and 3 different ending keywords then print whats in between to the same output text file.

So for example my output text document would look something like:

```
something
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
ENDkeyword1

something
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
Data6
ENDkeyword2

something
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
data6
data7
data8
ENDkeyword3
```

One brute force method I've tried is to make a loop to make the user input a new Keyword one at a time however whenever I try to write to the same Output File in the Text document it will over write the previous entry using Append. Is there any way to make it so a user can search a text document for multiple strings and print out the multiple results with or without a loop?

----------------- EDIT:

So many thanks to all of you Im getting closer with your tips to a nice finalized version or so.. This is my current code:

```
def process(infile, outfile, keywords):

    keys = [ [k[0], k[1], 0] for k in keywords ]
    endk = None
    with open(infile, "rb") as fdin:
        with open(outfile, "wb") as fdout:
            for line in fdin:
                if endk is not None:
                    fdout.write(line)
                    if line.find(endk) >= 0:
                        fdout.write("\n")
                        endk = None
                else:
                    for k in keys:
                        index = line.find(k[0])
                        if index >= 0:
                            fdout.write(line[index + len(k[0]):].lstrip())
                            endk = k[1]
                            k[2] += 1
    if endk is not None:
        raise Exception(endk + " not found before end of file")
    return keys



from Tkinter import *
import tkSimpleDialog
import tkMessageBox
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text ="Configuration Inspector")
w.pack()
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Welcome", "This is version 1.00 of Configuration Inspector ")
infile = askopenfilename() #
outfile = askopenfilename() #

start_token = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Serial Number", "What is the device serial number?")
end_token = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("End Keyword", "What is the end keyword")

process(infile,outfile,((start_token + ",SHOWALL",end_token),))
```

So far It works however now it's time to for part im getting myself lost on and that is a multiple string input separated by a Delimiter. So if i had inputted

> STARTKeyword1, STARTKeyword2, STARTKeyword3, STARTKeyword4

into the program prompt I want to be able to separate those keywords and place them into the

> process(infile,outfile,keywords)

function so that the user is only prompted to input once and allow for multiple strings to search through the files. I was thinking of using maybe a loop or creating the separated inputs into an array.

If this question is far from the original I ask I will close this one and open another so i can give credit where credit is due.

Comment: what if keywords overlap or you don't find an ending keyword?

Comment: If the text file can not find an ending keyword I believe it should exit and give the user an error. As for if the keywords overlap I haven't really thought of that since the text document usually is in a repeating order where you have a Starting Keyword Data in the middle then an Ending Keyword. I will have to try to create a text document with overlapping keyword to see what happens.

Comment: why are you opening the file for writing in the loop?

Comment: I was trying to force the file to basically reopen and act as if the program is reexecuting to allow the user to search multiple times for different strings. Since I do not know how to allow the user to just open the file once and search for multiple strings in one run.

Comment: Open the file outside the loop

Comment: Are the `ENDkeywords` always on a line of their own?

Comment: Yes they will always be on their own line in my case atleast. For example the end keyword is always going to be "[+][+]" no matter what however I'd like to add variety just incase.

Comment: Are you just looking for `split`: `start_tokens = [ x.strip() for x in "STARTKeyword1, STARTKeyword2, STARTKeyword3, STARTKeyword4".split(',') ]` ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I figured it out thank you I marked your answer as the correct one since it helped me reach my goal. I managed to nest the function you made into a for loop and just spilt the input strings into a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a separate function that takes:

- the path of the input file
- the path of the output file
- an iterable containing the (startkeyword, endkeyword) pairs

Then I would process the file line by line copying line if between a start and an end, counting how many time each pair has been found. That way caller could know what pairs were found and how many times for each.

Here is a possible implemenatation:

```
def process(infile, outfile, keywords):
    '''Search through inputfile whatever is between a pair startkeyword (excluded)
and endkeyword (included). Each chunk if copied to outfile and followed with
an empty line.
infile and outfile are strings representing file paths
keyword is an iterable containing pairs (startkeyword, endkeyword)

Raises an exception if  an endkeyword is not found before end of file

Returns a list of lists [ startkeyword, endkeyword, nb of occurences]'''
    keys = [ [k[0], k[1], 0] for k in keywords ]
    endk = None
    with open(infile, "r") as fdin:
        with open(outfile, "w") as fdout:
            for line in fdin:
                if endk is not None:
                    fdout.write(line)
                    if line.find(endk) >= 0:
                        fdout.write("\n")
                        endk = None
                else:
                    for k in keys:
                        index = line.find(k[0])
                        if index >= 0:
                            fdout.write(line[index + len(k[0]):].lstrip())
                            endk = k[1]
                            k[2] += 1
    if endk is not None:
        raise Exception(endk + " not found before end of file")
    return keys
```

Comment: Im not all that familiar with functions at the moment learning as i go along I will try to implement this into my current code and see how to input the multiple keywords. Going to start trying this function now and see what I can dig up with the results. Thank you +1

Comment: @JeanP: I implemented it as a function, because I could test it easily without the remaining of your code :-) . You can certainly include it directly. BTW, function and classes are useful to design properly structured scripts, but you'll learn that later...

Comment: so im working on troubleshooting a bit now with your function for some reason it will print out the whole document onto the output file if the string matches rather than whats in between the string.

Comment: hmm maybe its my fault. I have a question about the format of keywords in process(infile, outfile, keywords) should it be set like so process(infile, outfile, (STARTkeyword1, ENDkeyword1)) ? this is how I am setting it up currently and I apologize if thats a very "noobish" question because Im not too familiar with functions

Comment: @JeanP I create a copy of your example as `input.txt`, and wanted the result in `output.txt` in current dir. So I called it as `process('input.txt', 'output.txt', (('STARTkeyword1', 'ENDkeyword1'),  ('STARTkeyword3', 'ENDkeyword3')))` because I wanted to test for only two keywords - Note the 2 parenthese levels to have a tuple of tuples, and a tuple of one tuple would have been `(('STARTkeyword1', 'ENDkeyword1'),)` - note the last comma. Yes python syntax is generally nice but there are some caveats...

Comment: Interesting I've tried the code now using your tip but now another question has raised for the function process for this part of the code `with open(infile, "r") as fdin:` say i have a file with strange binary characters such as `”Ò‡ü»#` I thought about using "rb" like i did in original however i need to be able to use `reText = re.search("%s(.*?)%s" % (re.escape(start_token + ",SHOWALL"), re.escape(end_token)), f_input.read(), re.S)` in order to read the binary data in the file correctly? or is there an easily way to add this to the function?

Comment: The reason i ask is because my infile will content in the end some binary characters and Python doesn't read it correctly with the current "r" setup

Comment: **You** said it was a text file ;-) More seriously, if it contains *binary* characters you should open it in "rb" mode. The only problem, is that you will no longer have end line conversion, so you should open outfile in "wb" mode and... use the correct end of line (`\n` on Unixes `\r\n` on Windows for example) to print the empy line.

Comment: I have to really start correcting my lingo and learning more The file is in a .txt format but contents binary characters in between the lets call it unimportant data.  now these binary characters do NOT appear between the keywords (START -> END) but they do appear in the document. But yes thank you the "rb' and 'wb' worked ill continune some more testing after lunch. But so far your answer seems to be the best one to solve my issue thank you

Comment: This bit of code works in the example given above, but if you have a document like this, I don't think it'll work:
     
`something something
StartKeyWord1 something something StartKeyWord2
something something EndKeyWord1 something something EndKeyWord2`

Comment: @Metareven: In a comment on question OP said that it did need overlapping regions.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I've edit my original post to show where I am currently at with the code. Since I am new to the site and if my new edit is asking for a different question I will gladly close this question so that you may get credit . I apologize if I am asking too much :( trying to get the hang of this as best as i can and I do appreciate everyones hard work and comments.

Answer (score 0):

> I try to write to the same Output File in the Text document it will
>   over write the previous entry.

Have you tried using append rather than write?

```
f = open('filename', 'a')
```

Comment: I've tried to append in the loop sorry I forgot to add that to the original

Comment: Very strange behavior for append mode to overwrite. Perhaps you have an open('filename', 'w') somewhere else that is wiping it between loops?

Comment: Ill have to try to make a different loop in this case since Im not sure what's causing this either

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand the problem. But if I understand correctly, you can just have a list of lists, containing each start/end keyword couple. For each word in the document, check if it is equal to the first element in one of the lists (the start keyword). If it is, pop the keyword from the list (making the end-keyword be the first element of the list) and start saving all subsequent words into a string (different strings for each start/end keyword-couple). Once you hit the end keyword, just pop it from the list as well and remove the list that used to contain the start/end keywords from the surrounding list. At the end you should have 3 strings containing all the words between the different start/end keywords. Now just print all 3 of them to the file

EDIT:

If the main problem is that you're not able to append to the file, but you're actually rewriting the file every time, try opening the file this way instead of the way you're doing it today:

```
fo = open(outputfilename, "ab")
```

From the python docs:

"The first argument is a string containing the filename. The second argument is another string containing a few characters describing the way in which the file will be used. mode can be 'r' when the file will only be read, **'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased)**, and **'a' opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is automatically added to the end.** 'r+' opens the file for both reading and writing. The mode argument is optional; 'r' will be assumed if it’s omitted."

Comment: Why the minus without a comment?

Comment: Yes you are correct its a list of data that has keywords in the data that is important. So lets say I have 4 serial numbers i need to search in this file. I will just prompt the user to input the 4 serial numbers (STARTkeyword 1-4) then the end keyword (1-4)  and it will print the the resulting data for those serial numbers into a new document.

Comment: Im not sure about the minus to a comment. It wasn't me

Comment: Yes your edit did help me try to fix the current issue with over writting now Im trying to solve a new issue with the keywords and trying to allow multiple keywords in one input separated by delimiters. For example keyword1,keyword2,keyword3 etc then print those search results. Thank you again! I already +1

Answer (score 0):

This could be the beginning of something

```
import os
directory = os.getcwd()
path = directory + "/" + "textdoc.txt"

newFileName = directory + '/' + "data" + '.txt'
newFob = open(newFileName, 'w')

keywords = [["STARTkeyword1","ENDkeyword1"],["STARTkeyword2","ENDkeyword2"]]


fob = open(path, 'r')
objectLines = fob.readlines()

startfound=False

for keyword in keywords:
    for line in objectLines:

        if startfound and keyword[1] in line:
            startfound=False

        if startfound:
            newFob.write(line)

        if keyword[0] in line:
            startfound=True

newFob.close()
```

If a text called `textdoc.txt` with the data you have provided is in the current directory, the script will create a file in the current directory called  `data.txt` with the following output:

```
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
Data6
```

Ideally you would input more keywords, or allow the user to input some, and fill that up in the keywords list.

Comment: This code is kinda of what mine does currently where it's able to search a text document for a starting keyword and an ending keyword then print out the results to a new document. Where im curious and haven't a clue really is for the multiple start and ending keywords. I do not know to really implement it into my current code. Ill try to mess around with your code to see if I can force a loop for multiple key words

Comment: Sorry im still trying to test my code using your format and trying to see how i can implement my personal code. So far your answer is great and i've already +1. Im now trying to see how I can input a multiple keywords at once separated by a space as the delimiter then print out the results

Comment: oki cool, glad you got it working, however because of your -1 it equates to 0. :(

Comment: I dont know how you got a -1. But rest assured You have my +1 lol

Answer (score 0):

For each start/end pair, create a instance of a class, say Pair, with a feed(line) method, its start and key and a buffer or list to store data of interest.

Put all the pair instances in a list. Use those keywords to scan for matches and **feed** each of those Pair instances each line. If an instance is not between start and end keyword the Pair instance is inactive & forgets the data, otherwise **feed** adds it to its own StringBuffer or line list. Or even directly to your output file.

Write your file at end.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code using the following example text file.

```
something something something something
something something something something
something something something something
something something something something
something something something something
something something something something STARTkeyword3 something
data3
data3
data3
data3
data3
ENDkeyword3
something something something something
something something something something
something something something something
something something something something STARTkeyword1 something
data1
data1
data1
ENDkeyword1
something something something something
something something something something
something something something something
something something something something
something something something something STARTkeyword2 something
data2
data2
data2
Data2
ENDkeyword2
something something something something
something something something something
something something something something
something something something something
something something something something
something something something something STARTkeyword3 something
data3
data3
data3
data3
data3
ENDkeyword3
```

Visit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6LYa6X2Otg&feature=youtu.be

Here is the code:

```
## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Created by: James P. Lopez
## Created date: 9/21/2020
## Modified date: 9/29/2020, 10/20/2020
## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097118/search-text-file-for-multiple-strings-and-print-out-results-to-a-new-text-file
## Search text file for multiple strings and print out results to a new text file
## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
import time, datetime, string

############################################################################################
############ Adding date to end of output file name
start_c = datetime.datetime.now();##print start_c
c1 = (("%(start_c)s" % vars()).partition(' ')[0]);##print c1
new_str = string.replace(c1, '-', '_');new_str = "_"+new_str;##print(new_str)

#### Path
path = "S:\\PythonProjects\\TextFileReadWrite"
Bslash = "\\"

#### Text files
####    Read file
##filename1 = "openfilename1" ## This is the read file
#### Below sample with exceptions
filename1 = "openfilenameexception1" ## This is the read file
####    Write file
outputfilename1 = "writefilename2"  ## This is the write file

#### Text file extension
extT = ".txt"

#### Full Text file name
filename = ("%(path)s%(Bslash)s%(filename1)s%(extT)s" % vars());print filename
outputfilename = ("%(path)s%(Bslash)s%(outputfilename1)s%(new_str)s%(extT)s" % vars())
print outputfilename

#### Sum rows in text file
with open(filename) as filename1:
   SumReadFile = sum(1 for _ in filename1)
filename1.close()
##print SumReadFile

############################################################################################
############ Create text file if it does not exist
############ or truncate if it does exist
outputfilename2=open('%(outputfilename)s' % vars(),'w')
outputfilename2.close()

#### Counters
foundstart = 0
CountAllStartKeys = 0
CountAllEndKeys = 0
CountAllBetweenData = 0
CountAllRecordsProcessed = 0
    
#### Set of keys
s1 = 'STARTkeyword1';s2 = 'STARTkeyword2';s3 = 'STARTkeyword3'
e1 = 'ENDkeyword1';e2 = 'ENDkeyword2';e3 = 'ENDkeyword3'

#### Opening output file append
outputFiles=open('%(outputfilename)s' % vars(),'a')

SetOfKeys = [(s1,e1),(s2,e2),(s3,e3)]
for keys in SetOfKeys:
    print(keys)
    search1 = keys[0]; ##print search1 ## This is the start key
    search2 = keys[1]; ##print search2 ## This is the end key
    with open("%(filename)s"% vars(), "r") as readFile1:
        for line in readFile1:
            print line
            CountAllRecordsProcessed += 1
            if foundstart == 0:
                if search1 in line:
                    #### It will write the start key
                    print ("Yes found start key %(search1)s within line = %(line)s" % vars())
                    outputFiles.write(line)
                    foundstart += 1;CountAllStartKeys += 1
##                    time.sleep(2)
                    continue
            if foundstart >= 1:
                if search2 in line:
                    #### It will write the end key
                    print ("Yes found end key %(search2)s within line = %(line)s\nn" % vars())
                    outputFiles.write(line)
                    foundstart = 0;CountAllEndKeys += 1
##                    time.sleep(2)
                elif search1 in line:
                    #### It will append to output text file and write no end key found
                    print ("\nATTENTION!      No matching end key within line = %(line)s\n" % vars())
                    print ("\nHowever, found start key %(search1)s within line = %(line)s\n" % vars())
                    outputFiles.write("\nNo matching end key within line = %(line)s\n" % vars())
                    outputFiles.write("\nHowever, found start key %(search1)s within line = %(line)s\n" % vars())
                    outputFiles.write(line)
                    CountAllStartKeys += 1
##                    time.sleep(5)
                    continue
                else:
                    #### It will write the rows between start and end key
                    print ("Yes, found between data = %(line)s" % vars())
                    outputFiles.write(line)
                    CountAllBetweenData += 1
##                    time.sleep(2)
    readFile1.close()
outputFiles.close()

print "\nFinished Text File Read and Write"
print "\nTotal Number of Start Key Words Processed = " + str(CountAllStartKeys)
print "Total Number of End Key Words Processed   = " + str(CountAllEndKeys)
print "\nTotal Number of Between Data Processed    = " + str(CountAllBetweenData)
print "\nTotal Sum of Lines in Read File   = " + str(SumReadFile)
NumberOfSetOfKeys = CountAllRecordsProcessed / SumReadFile; ##print NumberOfSetOfKeys
print "Total Number of Set of Keys       = " + str(NumberOfSetOfKeys)
print "Total Number of Records Processed = " + str(CountAllRecordsProcessed)
print ("\n%(SumReadFile)s multiplied by %(NumberOfSetOfKeys)s = %(CountAllRecordsProcessed)s" % vars())
```

Answer (score 0):

This program will process the read file only once instead of my previous post which processed the start and end keys one at a time for a total of three full iterations. It has been tested with the sample data in my previous post.
Visit: https://youtu.be/PJjBftGhSNc

```
## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Created by: James P. Lopez
## Created date: 9/21/2020
## Modified date: 10/1/2020, 10/20/2020
## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097118/search-text-file-for-multiple-strings-and-print-out-results-to-a-new-text-file
## Search text file for multiple strings and print out results to a new text file
## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
import time, datetime, string

############################################################################################
############ Adding date to end of file name
start_c = datetime.datetime.now(); ##print start_c
c1 = (("%(start_c)s" % vars()).partition(' ')[0]); ##print c1
new_str = string.replace(c1, '-', '_');new_str = "_"+new_str;##print(new_str)

#### Path
path = "S:\\PythonProjects\\TextFileReadWrite"
Bslash = "\\"

#### Text files
####    Read file
##filename1 = "openfilename1" ## This is the read file
#### Below sample with exceptions
filename1 = "openfilenameexception1" ## This is the read file
####    Write file
outputfilename1 = "writefilename2"  ## This is the write file

#### Full Text file name
filename = ("%(path)s%(Bslash)s%(filename1)s.txt" % vars());print filename
outputfilename = ("%(path)s%(Bslash)s%(outputfilename1)s%(new_str)s.txt" % vars())
print outputfilename

#### Counters
foundstart = 0
CountAllStartKeys = 0
CountAllEndKeys = 0
CountAllBetweenData = 0
CountAllRecordsProcessed = 0
#### Start Key Not Found
SKNF = 0

#### Sum number or rows in text file
with open(filename) as filename1:
   SumReadFile = sum(1 for _ in filename1)
filename1.close()
print SumReadFile

#### Total set of keys
start1 = 'STARTkeyword1';start2 = 'STARTkeyword2';start3 = 'STARTkeyword3'
end1 = 'ENDkeyword1';end2 = 'ENDkeyword2';end3 = 'ENDkeyword3'

#### Count number of unique start and end keys
SK1 = 0;SK2 = 0;SK3 = 0;EK1 = 0;EK2 = 0;EK3 = 0
Keys = [start1,start2,start3,end1,end2,end3]
##print Keys
with open(filename) as filename1:
    for line in filename1:
##        print line
        if any(word in line for word in Keys):
            if start1 in line:
                SK1+=1
            elif start2 in line:
                SK2+=1
            elif start3 in line:
                SK3+=1
            elif end1 in line:
                EK1+=1
            elif end2 in line:
                EK2+=1
            elif end3 in line:
                EK3+=1 
filename1.close()

############################################################################################
############ Create if it does not exist or truncate if it does exist
outputfilename2=open('%(outputfilename)s' % vars(),'w')
outputfilename2.close()

### Opening output file to append data
outputFiles=open('%(outputfilename)s' % vars(),'a')

#### We are only checking for the start keys
StartKeys = [start1,start2,start3]
#### Opening and reading the first line in read text file
with open("%(filename)s"% vars(), "r") as readFile1:
    for line in readFile1:
        CountAllRecordsProcessed += 1
        #### We are checking if one of the StartKeys is in line
        if any(word in line for word in StartKeys):
            #### Setting the variables (s1 and e1) for the start and end keys
            if start1 in line:
                s1 = start1; e1 = end1; SKNF = 1; ##print ('%(s1)s , %(e1)s' % vars())
            elif start2 in line:
                s1 = start2; e1 = end2; SKNF = 1; ##print ('%(s1)s , %(e1)s' % vars())
            elif start3 in line:
                s1 = start3; e1 = end3; SKNF = 1; ##print ('%(s1)s , %(e1)s' % vars())
##                time.sleep(2)
        if foundstart == 0 and SKNF <> 0:
            if s1 in line:
                #### It will append to output text file and write the start key
                print ("Yes found start key %(s1)s within line = %(line)s" % vars())
                outputFiles.write(line)
                foundstart += 1; CountAllStartKeys += 1
##                    time.sleep(2)
                continue
        if foundstart >= 1 and SKNF <> 0:
            if e1 in line:
                #### It will append to output text file and write the end key
                print ("Yes found end key %(e1)s within line = %(line)s" % vars())
                outputFiles.write(line)
                foundstart = 0; SKNF = 0; CountAllEndKeys += 1
##                    time.sleep(2)
            elif s1 in line:
                #### It will append to output text file and write no end key found
                print ("\nATTENTION!      No matching end key within line = %(line)s\n" % vars())
                print ("\nHowever, found start key %(s1)s within line = %(line)s\n" % vars())
                outputFiles.write("\nNo matching end key within line = %(line)s\n" % vars())
                outputFiles.write("\nHowever, found start key %(s1)s within line = %(line)s\n" % vars())
                outputFiles.write(line)
                CountAllStartKeys += 1
##                    time.sleep(2)
                continue
            else:
                #### It will append to output text file and write the rows between start and end key
                print ("Yes found between data = %(line)s" % vars())
                outputFiles.write(line)
                CountAllBetweenData += 1
##                    time.sleep(2)

#### Closing read and write text files
readFile1.close()
outputFiles.close()

print "\nFinished Text File Read and Write"

print '\nTotal Number of Unique Start Keys'
print ("%(start1)s = " % vars())+str(SK1)
print ("%(start2)s = " % vars())+str(SK2)
print ("%(start3)s = " % vars())+str(SK3)
print "Total Number of Start Key Words Processed = " + str(CountAllStartKeys)
print '\nTotal Number of Unique End Keys'
print ("%(end1)s = " % vars())+str(EK1)
print ("%(end2)s = " % vars())+str(EK2)
print ("%(end3)s = " % vars())+str(EK3)
print "Total Number of End Key Words Processed   = " + str(CountAllEndKeys)
print "\nTotal Number of Between Data Processed    = " + str(CountAllBetweenData)
print "\nTotal Sum of Lines in Read File   = " + str(SumReadFile)
print "Total Number of Records Processed = " + str(CountAllRecordsProcessed)
```